# Dynamic length dropdown

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create the drop down list in  the front end with dynamic length.

The length is not fixed here and the list will be numeric which will always start from `0` to up to length. I have no idea about jQuery so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be sharing relevant code and what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
          <input id="cnt" type="text" name="count" size="10" />
          <input id="gen" type="button" name="generate" value="generate" />
          <select name="sel" id="ddlb"></select>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
$('#gen').on('click', function () {
  if ($('#cnt').val().trim() !== "") {
    var index = 0;
    $('#ddlb').html("");
    while (index < $('#cnt').val()) {
        $('#ddlb').append($('<option>', {
            value: index,
            text: index
        }));
        index++;
    }
  }
});
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/aDqhH/6/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Its awesome dreamweiver. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            $("#mySelect").append($("<option>", { html: i }));
        }
    });

</script>
<body>
 <select id="mySelect"></select>
</body>
```